# How to stop a puppeteer scrape after a given selector?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm facing the same kind of problem as [Joppe's issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62004013/scrape-p-tags-between-h2-tags-with-puppeteer)... and I'm also quite a newbie on [puppeteer](/questions/tagged/puppeteer) as well.

I've tried to implement @vsemozhebuty 's solution in my piece of code but when I run it I have a `TypeError: compareDocumentPosition is not a function`

My use-case is the following: I want to scrape links included in `<h3>` tags but only for a selection of tags, the ones upper a defined selector (a div with an id of `trend_container`).

So my code is:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const getAllUrl = async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://UrlOfTheWebpageToScrape/');
  await page.waitFor('body');
  
  const articlesUrl = await page.evaluate(() =>
    [...document.querySelectorAll('h3 a')].map(link => link.href));

  const endScrape = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('div[id="trend_container"]'));

  articlesUrl.filter(link => link.compareDocumentPosition(endScrape) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING);
  
  return articlesUrl; 
};
```

Can't see where I do it wrong...

Comment: Clearly `compareDocumentPosition` does not exist on the target page, so try not to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your approach:

1. `articlesUrl` is an array of strings (URLs), so you cannot use `.compareDocumentPosition()` method with its content — this method needs nodes, document elements.
2. `endScrape` will not get the div element as you cannot transfer HTML elements from browser context to Node.js context, they are not serializable.

Try to get all the serializable data within one `page.evaluate()` and tranfer this data:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function getAllUrl() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://UrlOfTheWebpageToScrape/');
    await page.waitFor('body');

    const articlesUrl = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const endScrape = document.querySelector('div[id="trend_container"]');
      return [...document.querySelectorAll('h3 a')].filter(
        link => link.compareDocumentPosition(endScrape) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING
      ).map(link => link.href);
    });

    console.log(articlesUrl);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot vsemozhebuty !
It's working perfectly :)